# WebExtensions and Firefox Android: How to get a BrowserApp object

Tags: javascript, android, firefox-addon-webextensions

The MDN [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/API/BrowserApp) for the `BrowserApp` object says that it is an alternative way to access some properties that you otherwise could not get to on Android. But the way they show how to actually get one of these objects uses the deprecated 'old-style' API that does not work in my extension.

I need a way for my background script to get a hold of one of these `BrowserApp` objects, how do I do this? I know that if I use a bootstrap script, the browser will give me one, but I need it in my background script.

I can't use the above `var { Cu } = require("chrome")` method because `"chrome"` is not loaded yet by the time my script runs.

(as an aside, does anyone know if the `browser.downloads.download(...)` api works on Android? The MDN says it will but the MDN says a lot of things, and at this point I'm wary of blindly trusting the docs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access BrowserApp by design from webextensions.  Your best bet is probably asking about the individual things you want to get at via BrowserApp.

Comment: Ah, thats too bad. Wish the documentation had mentioned that (or maybe I missed it). Am I just SOL for accessing tabs in a WebExtension?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "accessing tabs".  As of Firefox 54 (currently available as Firefox Beta), most of the webextensions tabs api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs) is available on Android.

Comment: I need the query API, to be able to get all the current tabs. But it's not there yet.

Comment: `browser.tabs.query()` is supported, beginning with Firefox 54.

Comment: So now I just need to wait for Firefox Android to get to v54